# Market Basket Analysis taking quantity in account

Tags: python, unsupervised-learning, market-basket-analysis

I am using apriori algorithm to extract frequent itemsets and then performing a Market Basket Analysis.

As an input for the apriori, I have to perform a one_hot encoding on my dataset: the quantities are ignored.

[image]

Is there a way to perform Market Basket Analysis using an algorithm that takes in account the quantity of the products?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I also want to do quantitative market basket analysis. I found the below link, but that converts all the positive values to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Apriori algorithm does take into account 'Quantity' column. You can refer to this article https://pbpython.com/market-basket-analysis.html. If you don't have 'Quantity' column and want to create one then just add a column and set all the rows as 1

Comment: I've read the article you've provided but couldn't find any explicit reference to how it handles the quantity. Any chance you can explain this bit? Thank you.